# Why does accessible_attributes have an empty string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm just trying to understand part of Rails, specifically around accessible_attributes

See example below:

```
irb(main):001:0> Ec2TypeSpecification.accessible_attributes
=> #<ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::WhiteList: {"", "api_name", "api_size", "api_type", "cores", "core_type", "compute_units", "ebs_optimization", "ephemeral_drives", "io_performance", "max_ips", "memory", "name", "support_32_bit", "support_64_bit", "total_ephemeral_storage"}>
```

Why the empty string? What does it do? 
Or, is there something broken with my model?

`gem 'rails', '3.2.13'`

EDIT: add model

That's the whole model (I'm not very far in my project)

```
class Ec2TypeSpecification < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :api_name, :api_size, :api_type, :cores, :core_type, :compute_units, :ebs_optimization, 
    :ephemeral_drives, :io_performance, :max_ips, :memory, :name, :support_32_bit, :support_64_bit, 
    :total_ephemeral_storage 
end
```

Comment: Can you past in part of your model?

Answer (score 3):

It represents the default :

```
attr_accessible nil
```

A blank whitelist is a wide-open whitelist, so this default just requires you to specify the other params you want to mass assign as attr_accessible.  Instead of a blank whitelist, it's a whitelist containing nil.

```
# nil.to_s  = ""
```